# Comparing string and text, character by character

Tags: java, arrays, string, user-interface

I am making a Typing game.When the user enters a key the program should compare it with the stored string/array. If it matches the character at that index the score variable should be incremented.

I am trying to store the entered text in a string and then compare it after breaking it into characters.

```
         text=new JTextField(40);
         String sentence="the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
         String store=text.getText();
         for (int i = 0; i < store.length(); i++) {
             if(store[i]==sentence.charAt(i)) {        //error
                 score++;
             }
         }
```

increment "score" if entered key matches the character else decrement.

Comment: `store` is not an array

Comment: Both `store` and `sentence` are Strings. Based on `sentence.charAt(i)` you are familiar with how to get single character at specified position, so why are you using `store[i]`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `store` variable is also a String not an array, so you have to use `.charAt()`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(store.length(), sentence.length()); i++) {
    if(store.charAt(i) == sentence.charAt(i)) {
        score++;
    } else {
        score--;
    }
}
```

You should also use `Math.min(store.length(), sentence.length())` to prevent an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: Why `score--` ?

Comment: OP wrote in the question _"increment "score" if entered key matches the character else decrement."_

Comment: Okay. I missed that :)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Samuel Philipp on using `.charAt().` I would like to add on, though.
`.charAt()` searches for a character at the index given. Based on your level, I feel that this method would be to your liking.